# MacBook Retina strange system/battery behaviour

Tags: macos, battery, macbook-pro

There two things that I seek to understand about my new MacBook Pro Retina.

My `pmset -g` configuration is as follows with `hibernatemode` is off:

```
Currently in use:
 standbydelay         4200
 standby              1
 womp                 1
 halfdim              1
 hibernatefile        /var/vm/sleepimage
 gpuswitch            2
 darkwakes            1
 networkoversleep     0
 disksleep            10
 sleep                10
 hibernatemode        0
 ttyskeepawake        1
 displaysleep         10
 acwake               0
 lidwake              1
```

1. When I was using my notebook at the very beginning it was running on batteries until almost drained. At about 1% I rebooted it, but instead of rebooting it presented me a nice empty battery pictogram (just one you may know from iOS devices). I pushed power-on button several times just to see the very nice pictogram again. I left the notebook off then and started looking for a charger. After a few seconds, the MacBook Pro powered itself (!) back on. Still on battery! I pressed Option and waited on boot screen until it turned off again - but this lasted for long minutes.
2. Having it recharged to 100% I used it on battery again. This time I didn't notice that it went down to 0% while I still had my system booted and many applications open. I glanced to notice a "running on reserve battery power" warning then the screen went blank. Pushing power-on button - no action. I simply put a charger in and went to sleep. In the morning another suprise: I open the lid and see that the system didn't actually shut off. It is up and all my applications are still running. So at 0% battery it simply went to some "sleep" mode.

My guessing is that either battery is somehow uncalibrated and provides more power than the system expects from it, or the MacBook Pro with ML is keeping some additional non-reported reserve of power below displayed 0%. Or am I wrong? It's a pity that the nice sleep indicator was removed from the chassis - without you never actually know what your system is doing right now.

Comment: The best part is that OS X kind of dump your current system to the disk so it can come back right to where it went out of power. Kind of how most iOS apps works when put to background. Another interesting thing is that I experienced "shutdown" by lack of power but the Mac doesn't shut down totally. The sleep light was still pulsing and such.

Comment: From what I know - disabling `hibernatemode` causes OS X not to dump memory to disk.

Comment: I just read about how hibernate to be unnecessary as the HFS+ keeps track of changes and updates to the drive.

Answer (score 1):

macbooks generally hibernate (save your ram's state to your hdd) when the battery is too low.
to do that efficiently (without losing data) there's an internal threshold that keeps some energy for the system to save state.

in general, you don't shut down (as in "windows is shutting down") your mac. you either let it go to sleep after some time or just close the lid (and trigger hibernation). you can even trigger hibernation from the apple menu.

Comment: Sorry but this is not true here. I made a statement on `hibermantemode` on purpose. I even do not have hibernation data file on my drive (`/var/rm/sleepimage`).